# Keyword Driven Framework-Getting Error java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, selenium, nullpointerexception

I am new to Keyword Driven approach for selenium. I am getting `NullPointerException` while running below `ExecuteTest.java`

**Folder Structure**

1. [Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9EG1.png)

**Object.txt**

1. [Object.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54pKQ.png)

**TestCase.xlsx**

1. [TestCase.xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdJk2.png)

**Error Screenshot**

1. [Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUmrb.png)
2. [Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGAmm.png)

   Adding Debug screenshots
   [screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2u3C.png)
   [screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVcTV.png)
   [screenshot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMexj.png)

**ReadGuru99Excel.java**

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

public class ReadGuru99ExcelFile {

    public Sheet readExcel (String filePath,String fileName, String sheetName)throws IOException{
        File file = new File(filePath+"\\"+fileName);
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        Workbook guru99Workbook = null;

        String fileExtensionName = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf("."));

        if(fileExtensionName.equals(".xlsx")){
            guru99Workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        } else if(fileExtensionName.equals(".xls")) {
            guru99Workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        }
        Sheet guru99Sheet =guru99Workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
        return guru99Sheet;
    }
}
```

**ReadObject.Java**

```
package operation;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.File;

public class ReadObject {   

    Properties p = new Properties();

    public Properties getObjectRepository()throws IOException{

        InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File (System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\objects\\object.txt"));

        p.load(stream);
        return p;
    }
}
```

**UIOperation.java**

```
package operation;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;

public class UIOperation {
    WebDriver driver ;

    public UIOperation(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver; 
    }

    public void perform(Properties p, String operation, String objectName, String objectType, String value) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("");
        switch(operation.toUpperCase()){
            case "CLICK":
                driver.findElement(this.getObject(p, objectName, objectType)).click();
                break;
            case "SETTEXT":
                driver.findElement(this.getObject(p, objectName, objectType)).sendKeys(value);
                break;
            case "GOTOURL":
                driver.get(p.getProperty(value));
                break;
            case "GETTEXT":
                driver.findElement(this.getObject(p, objectName, objectType)).getText();
                break;
            default:
                break;
       }
   }
   private By getObject(Properties p, String objectName, String objectType) throws Exception{
      if(objectType.equalsIgnoreCase("XPATH")){
          return By.xpath(p.getProperty(objectName));
      }else if(objectType.equalsIgnoreCase("CLASSNAME")){
          return By.className(p.getProperty(objectName));
      }else if(objectType.equalsIgnoreCase("NAME")){
          return By.name(p.getProperty(objectName));
      }else if(objectType.equalsIgnoreCase("CSS")){
          return By.cssSelector(p.getProperty(objectName));
      }else if(objectType.equalsIgnoreCase("LINK")){
          return By.linkText(p.getProperty(objectName));
      }else if(objectType.equalsIgnoreCase("PARTIALLINK")){
          return By.partialLinkText(p.getProperty(objectName));
      }else{
          throw new Exception("Wrong object type");
      }
   }
}
```

**ExecuteTest.java**

```
package testcases;
import java.util.Properties;
import operation.ReadObject;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.MarionetteDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import operation.UIOperation;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import excelExportAndFileIO.ReadGuru99ExcelFile;

public class ExecuteTest {

    @Test
    public void testLogin()throws Exception{
        /**
         * System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:\\Selenium-2017\\geckodriver-v0.18.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
         * //Now you can Initialize marionette driver to launch firefox
         * DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
         * capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
         * WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebdriver(capabilities); 
         *
         * WebDriver webdriver = new FirefoxDriver();
         **/
        WebDriver driver;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\Selenium-2017\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        ReadGuru99ExcelFile file = new ReadGuru99ExcelFile();
        ReadObject object = new ReadObject();
        Properties allObjects = object.getObjectRepository();
        UIOperation operation = new UIOperation(driver);
        Sheet guru99Sheet = file.readExcel(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\test-output","TestCase.xlsx","KeywordFramework");
        int rowCount =guru99Sheet.getLastRowNum()-guru99Sheet.getFirstRowNum();

        System.out.println("first step clear");

        for(int i = 0;i<rowCount+1; i++){
            Row row  =guru99Sheet.getRow(i);
            System.out.println("2nd clear");
            if(row.getCell(0).toString().length()==0){
                System.out.println("4nd clear");
                System.out.println(row.getCell(1).toString()+"-----"+row.getCell(2).toString()+"----"+row.getCell(3).toString()+"---"+row.getCell(4).toString());
                System.out.println("3rd clear");
                operation.perform(allObjects, row.getCell(1).toString(), row.getCell(2).toString(), row.getCell(3).toString(), row.getCell(4).toString());  

            } else
                System.out.println("New Testcase->" + row.getCell(0).toString()+"Started");
            System.out.println("testerassumption");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception..., Have tried debugging?

Comment: Hi..@santhoshkumar.I tried debugging and have attached the screenshot of debugging result,not getting clear which line is throwing exception?? please refer to it .Thanks!!! for the help

Comment: Please don't provide *screenshots* for plain text. Include the text directly in the post.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Sure,going forward I will keep that in mind.Thanks!!

Comment: Why "going forward"? There's nothing stopping you from editing the exceptions into your post now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, please see this wonderful [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) about `NullPointerException` and how to fix it.

In your case, the stacktrace points the `NullPointerException` to be occuring at line 49 of the code in `ExecuteTest.java`, which points to this line of code

```
 operation.perform(allObjects, row.getCell(1).toString(), row.getCell(2).toString(), row.getCell(3).toString(), row.getCell(4).toString());
```

The issue here is that when you're trying to convert the contents of the cell in the `getCell()` method to a String, if there is nothing in the cell, then there would always be a `NullPointerException`.

You can either place a `!= null` check before every cell or add a `" "` for every `toString()` method, like

```
  operation.perform(allObjects, (row.getCell(1)+"").toString(), (row.getCell(2)+"").toString(), (row.getCell(3)+"").toString(), (row.getCell(4)+"").toString());
```

Comment: Thanks!! @demouser123  by adding " " for every toString( ) I am not getting any null pointer exception now.It works!!  Thanks for sharing the Post link ,It helped me a lot in understanding null pointer exception.